# bad handshake error with httpie ssl certificates

Tags: ssl, certificate, http

I'm running my Django backend on my local machine and trying to connect to it with `HTTPie` (https://httpie.org/).

When I run `python manage.py runsslserver` it gives me this output:

```
Starting development server at https://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using SSL certificate: //anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sslserver/certs/development.crt
Using SSL key: //anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sslserver/certs/development.key
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

When I try to connect to localhost using that certificate and key as per [the documentation](https://httpie.org/doc#server-ssl-certificate-verification):

```
http --cert=//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sslserver/certs/development.crt --cert-key=//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sslserver/certs/development.key https://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

I get a bad handshake error:

```
http: error: SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL 
routines','ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify 
failed')],)",) while doing GET request to URL: https://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Why isn't it connecting?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "httpie"?

Comment: @Ramhound https://httpie.org/ I thought this was a well known tool for sending http requests. Will most people not know what this is?

Comment: I assumed you thought thats how you spelled `http`........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the HTTPie documentation that you linked, it appears you are not using the `http` command correctly. The `--cert` and `-cert-key` options that you specified are for client certificate authentication (in place of an API token, for example). I can't be sure, but I am guessing that you are not using client certificate authentication.

Assuming that you have a **self-signed SSL Certificate** at `//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sslserver/certs/development.crt`, you have two main options:

### Treat the Self-Signed Certificate as a CA

> **Note:**  You should be sure you have the right certificate, or you risk the same issues as the second option below

```
http --verify=//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sslserver/certs/development.crt https://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

or, with `wget` or `curl`:

```
curl --cacert //anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sslserver/certs/development.crt https://127.0.0.1:8000/
wget --ca-certificate=//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sslserver/certs/development.crt https://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

### Skip SSL Validation

> **Note:** This method will still *encrypt* your data, but make no attempt to *authenticate* the remote endpoint (i.e. you could be encrypting data and sending it to an attacker). Therefore, this is **NOT RECOMMENDED for production use**.

```
http --verify=no https://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Also, note that there are other, more commonly-used command-line http clients:

```
curl -k https://127.0.0.1:8000/
wget --no-check-certificate https://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

### Let's Encrypt

Finally, you might consider getting a valid SSL certificate. [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) offers them for free, and there are many other CAs that you could consider if you want to pay someone something. With a valid SSL certificate (and a valid DNS name), no additional options should be needed on any of the clients mentioned.

Comment: How can I be sure I'm using the right certificate?

Comment: @MatthewDrill for the client or for the server?